# Printf with string does not work(2 ways: function return value and just a value)

Tags: c

So, my problem is whenever I want to print %s (char *), the program shows an empty string. Here is my code and I numbered all the questions inside the comments in the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *decToBinary(char *num, int size);

int main(){
    char *n;
    n = (char *)malloc(5);  
    //memset(n, 0, 5);
    printf("Enter n: ");

    // getting the number as a string
    scanf("%s", n);
    int size = 33;
    char *binNum;
    binNum = (char *)malloc(size);  
    memset(binNum, 0, size);

    //copying the (char *) which is returned by function to char binNum[33] 
    strcpy(binNum, decToBinary(n, size));

    //sprintf(binNum, "%s", decToBinary(n, size));

    // Printing the FUNCTION variable as a character in a loop. WORKS(WHY?)(3)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("With function: %c", decToBinary(n, size)[i]);
    }
    //Printing the variable binNum as a string <--------- DOES NOT WORK. JUST EMPTY MESSAGE(WHY?)(4)
    printf("In main: %s\n", binNum);

    // Printing the variable binNum as a character in a loop <------------ DOES NOT WORK(5)
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("with variable: %c", binNum[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

char *decToBinary(char *num, int size){
    // convert decimal to binary
    int i = size - 2;
    int remainder;
    int decimal;
    char *binary;
    int n;
    n = atoi(num); 
    binary = (char *)malloc(size);
    binary[size - 1] = '\0';
    memset(binary, 0, size);
    do{
        remainder = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        binary[i] = remainder + '0';
        i--;
    }while(n);
    printf("decToBinary = %s\n", binary); // does not work as string (1)
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        printf("%c", binary[j]); // but this works(2)
    }
    printf("\n");
    return binary;   
}
```

- (1) The string is not displayed in the function. Even if I flush the
  buffer by using "\n"
- (2) But when I use "for" loop and display each element of the array
  using %c - it works. But this is not a good way to make it work
- (3) In main() function printf of every element of return value from
  the function works fine even though I do not get the idea how it can
  work, because as I understood,the function is invoked 33 times and
  the value is returned 33 times and here I just read one element by
  one. That's bad practice I think.
- (4) So I copied the returned value from function to the variable
  binNum and tried to display it using %s, but again empty string is
  displayed.
- (5) Same thing with variable but using "for" loop and %c. Also did
  not work

So, my question is how to manage these problems?

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add a simple example of input, actual output and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code a bit

```
    for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        printf("%c 0x%02x\n", binary[j], binary[j]); // but this works(2)
    }
```

you will see the leading `'\0'` in your result:

```
With function: 1decToBinary =
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
 0x00
1 0x31
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
0 0x30
1 0x31
1 0x31
 0x00
```

So there is something wrong in your function `decToBinary`.

You count with `i` from the end of the array, so depending on the input you may not reach the beginning of the array.

You can try `return binary+i+1;` at the end of `decToBinary`. This will return a pointer to the character you have written last. Note that you should not iterate over `size` characters of the result but only up to a `'\0`.

This is not the final solution because you use `malloc` to allocate the character array in `decToBinary`. This means you should return the pointer you got from `malloc` and call `free` in the calling function.

To allow this you can use an additional loop that copies all characters from index `i+1` up to a `'\0'` to the start of the array.

```
    for(i++, j=0; binary[i]; i++, j++) {
        binary[j] = binary[i];
    }
    binary[j] = '\0';

    /* ... */

    return binary;
```

Additional note:

Code like this creates a memory leak because you don't `free` the results of repeated calls to `decToBinary`:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("With function: %c", decToBinary(n, size)[i]);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I will try to use your advices. Thank you very much again